# Update margin after RenderTransform

Tags: c#, wpf

I have applied `TranslateTransform` on a control, but the control's margin remains the same.

```
var margin = this.Margin;
this.RenderTransform = new TranslateTransform(diff.X, diff.Y);
if (diff.X != 0 && diff.Y != 0)
{
    if (margin == this.Margin)
        MessageBox.Show("Margins are equal");            
}
```

I want margin to be "updated" after Transform. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it automatically, because `RenderTransform` will not affect any Layout properties.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750596.aspx#transformClassesSection)

> RenderTransform – A transform that modifies the appearance of the
>   element but is applied after the layout pass is complete. By using the
>   RenderTransform property instead of the LayoutTransform property, you
>   can obtain performance benefits.

And you can't use a `LayoutTransform` instead.

> Note that, when they are used with the LayoutTransform property,
>   TranslateTransform objects appear to have no effect on elements.

Comment: I've tried this
    this.Margin = new Thickness(diff.X,diff.Y,0,0);

But it just double the change

Comment: And you have removed the RenderTransform?

Comment: Now it's ok.
I'm trying to make CustomControl draggable by mouse.
There are still some problems but I'll solve them, thank You :)

Comment: Then I recommend wrapping your CustomControl into a Canvas and using it's [Attached Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas_attachedproperties) for positioning.

Comment: Maybe it's too complicated, but I'll try that too.